# Null Reference Exception in SQL Query output

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, nullreferenceexception

After struggling with pulling certain info from a SQL Database to use in C# code to do some permission checking, I have decided to go back to basics and learn how to do it properly and slowly build on my skills so I can eventually do what I need to do.  The object of the below code is to grab the current Active Directory user, then go into a SQL table that contains usernames and other info, find one that matches and then display it in a MessageBox.

```
string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HSEProjRegConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE [username] LIKE '@currentUser'";

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@currentUser", SqlDbType.Char).Value = currentUser;

    MessageBox.Show("{0}", Convert.ToString((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()));

    cn.Close();
}
```

Something is wrong though.  I get the following error and Stack Trace.  Line 38 is the MessageBox line.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
HSE_project_Register.admin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in S:\IT\Development\Visual Studio Projects\HSE Project Register\admin\admin.aspx.cs:38
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

What is causing the Null Reference Exception in that code?  If the answer is in the Stack Trace, could someone please explain that to me?  I find the Stack Trace extremely confusing.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this exception because the value returned from:

```
(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

is in fact `null`. However, what interests me the most here is this. Your query says:

```
SELECT username FROM [tbl_Person]...
```

but then you're taking the results of that and trying to cast it to an `int`. It doesn't feel right to me. It seems this `Convert.ToString((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar())` should actually be this `cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string`. This would both handle `null`'s as well as cast its type properly.

And to fix your query, consider the following code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE [username] LIKE @currentUser";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", "%" + currentUser + "%";
```

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense.  Does that mean my Query is incorrect then since it is meant to output something that I would later use to make a comparison in C#?

Comment: @Trido, please have a look at my edit and respond to that. The query and your code don't *seem* to jive to me.

Comment: That did work and while nothing displays, it has fixed my error.  I thought it might be something to do with the type cast, but honestly I've struggled with how to convert it to a string.  This solved that issue nicely and is much easier to read.  Instead of a MessageBox, I just set it as a Label as that was easier.  The Label is blank which is good because you're right that it was returning a `null`.  I just have to figure out what's wrong with the query as I want it to output the username, assuming it is the query of course.

Comment: @Trido, fantastic. I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: @Trido, please see my edit to assist you with getting the query working properly.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly and gave me exactly what I was wanting and expecting.  I have a question though, why the percent signs around currentUser?  Is it the same as Environment Variables in Windows?

Comment: @Trido, those percent signs are required for the `LIKE` operator in MSSQL. It's a **wildcard** and so no, nothing like the environment variables in windows. In other words, give me anything that contains the string between the percent signs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your query to something like

```
SELECT username FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE [username] LIKE '%' + @currentUser + '%'
```

Also, you are not getting a casting exception, but a null reference exception.

So you need to tell us what is at line 38 of your page admin.aspx.cs?

Why dont you change the query to something like

```
SELECT COUNT(username) as Cnt_UserName 
FROM [tbl_Person] 
WHERE [username] LIKE '%' + @currentUser + '%'
```

Which should always return an Int

I think the issue is with the type `SqlDbType.Char`. Try changing that to `SqlDbType.VarChar`.

Have a look at the following demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a460d/4)

From [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> A string comparison using a pattern that contains char and varchar
>   data may not pass a LIKE comparison because of how the data is stored.

Comment: I did, the Messagebox line which is `MessageBox.Show("{0}", Convert.ToString((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()));`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

problem is with your sql statement

`LIKE '@currentUser'"`

this will not identified as parameter you better do as below

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM [tbl_Person] WHERE [username] LIKE @currentUser";
```

and when you set parameter

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", '%' + currentUser + '%');
```